# Compiling program gives "undefined reference"

Tags: c++

I'm lost here. I've been compiling my program successfully on LLVM on my Mac, but when I went to a Linux server and attempted to use g++ to compile, I got a boat load of linker errors.

Here's an excerpt:

```
/tmp/ccGbgd6T.o: In function `Scene::setBackgroundImage(String)':
Project.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `Graph_lib::Image::Image(Point, String, Graph_lib::Suffix::Encoding)'
/tmp/ccGbgd6T.o: In function `Graph_lib::Window::~Window()':
Project.cpp:(.text._ZN9Graph_lib6WindowD2Ev[_ZN9Graph_lib6WindowD5Ev]+0xc): undefined reference to `vtable for Graph_lib::Window'
/tmp/ccGbgd6T.o: In function `Graph_lib::Shape::~Shape()':
Project.cpp:(.text._ZN9Graph_lib5ShapeD2Ev[_ZN9Graph_lib5ShapeD5Ev]+0xb): undefined reference to `vtable for Graph_lib::Shape'
/tmp/ccGbgd6T.o: In function `Graph_lib::Text::Text(Point, String const&)':
Project.cpp:(.text._ZN9Graph_lib4TextC2E5PointRK6String[_ZN9Graph_lib4TextC5E5PointRK6String]+0xe): undefined reference to `Graph_lib::Shape::Shape()'
Project.cpp:(.text._ZN9Graph_lib4TextC2E5PointRK6String[_ZN9Graph_lib4TextC5E5PointRK6String]+0x17): undefined reference to `vtable for Graph_lib::Text'
Project.cpp:(.text._ZN9Graph_lib4TextC2E5PointRK6String[_ZN9Graph_lib4TextC5E5PointRK6String]+0x67): undefined reference to `Graph_lib::Shape::add(Point)'
/tmp/ccGbgd6T.o: In function `Graph_lib::Button::Button(Point, int, int, String const&, void (*)(void*, void*))':
Project.cpp:(.text._ZN9Graph_lib6ButtonC2E5PointiiRK6StringPFvPvS5_E[_ZN9Graph_lib6ButtonC5E5PointiiRK6StringPFvPvS5_E]+0x40): undefined reference to `vtable for Graph_lib::Button'
```

This scared me, but then I noticed that all the errors are coming from the same class: `Graph_lib`. Here's an extremely cut out version of what `Graph.h` looks like: (note, this is not my class)

```
#ifndef GRAPH_GUARD
#define GRAPH_GUARD 1

#include <...system stuff...>

namespace Graph_lib {
// lots of other classes in here
// this is just one
    struct Image : Shape {
        Image(Point xy, string file_name, Suffix::Encoding e = Suffix::none);
    //rest of class
    }
}
```

What could be going wrong here?

Edit: this is the command I'm using to compile:

```
g++-4.6 -std=c++0x *.cpp -lfltk -lfltk_images
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though you have forgotten to link your project with `Graph.cpp`, or whatever file(s) hold the implementations of the `Graph_lib` class methods.

Comment: Would make sense. I've put Graph.cpp in a folder named `include`, and my other files are one directory up. How might I link this file? I've edited my original post to show how I'm currently compiling.

Comment: Usually, an `include` directory just contains `.h` files. But anyway, you could do something like: `g++-4.6 -std=c++0x *.cpp include/Graph.cpp -lfltk -lfltk_images`

Comment: You know, I just got rid of the include directory and oh good Lord it worked. You saved me from getting some grey hairs there, my good fellow. May the force be with you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Graph library is missing.

When linking using `g++, use -l <Graph lib>`